# Deep linking into Facebook group for Android Facebook Lite users

Tags: java, android, deep-linking, facebook-apps

I have an Android app which is trying to open a Facebook group page.
I followed some advice I found and got the al:android:url URL from the source of the group's web page, which is something along the lines of: fb://group/{group id}.

So with that, I'm able to open the group page in Facebook's app using this:

```
try {
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);
    startActivity(browserIntent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // fallback to opening the original group URL in a browser, i.e. https://www.facebook.com/groups/{group name}/
}
```

This works for the standard Facebook app.

However, it doesn't work for the Facebook Lite app!
Using the original URL (in the fallback block) will launch the Facebook Lite app but will not navigate to the group page.

Is there any way of deep linking to a group page in the Facebook Lite app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently using the URL format https://www.facebook.com/groups/{group id}/ instead works for both Facebook apps.